# Jquery reload every second while scrolled down in the beginning

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to make a div reload every second and to have it scrolled down in the beginning. Right know I put both in the same function, because scrolling script doesn't work when they are apart (because of the reloading). However, in this case it scrolls down every second. Is there a way to have the div scrolled down only in the beginning and reload it every second? Thanks!

```
<script>
    function load(){
        $('#screen').load('includes/update.php');
        $("#screen").scrollTop($("#screen")[0].scrollHeight);
    }
    setInterval(function(){
        load();
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the *complete* `callback function` for `.load()` like this:

```
<script>
    function load(){
        $('#screen').load('includes/update.php', function(){
            $("#screen").scrollTop($("#screen")[0].scrollHeight);
        });
    }
    setInterval(function(){
        load();
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

And it means that when the content is loaded fully, then call the callback functions and scroll to the top.

For more reference you can use the [jQuery .load() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: It still executes scrolling script every time it reloads. However I combined both answers (added scrolled variable like in Alex's answer to your method) and now it works. Thanks to both of you! Here is how it looks: var scrolled = false;
        function load(){
            $('#screen').load('includes/update.php', function(){
                if (!scrolled) {
                    $("#screen").scrollTop($("#screen")[0].scrollHeight);
                    scrolled = true;
                };
            });
        }
        setInterval(function(){
            load();
        }, 1000);

Comment: Great. Have fun coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You could have an outher variable that says if you have scrolled or not :

```
<script>
    var scrolled = false;
    function load(){
        $('#screen').load('includes/update.php');
        if(!scrolled){                
            $("#screen").scrollTop($("#screen")[0].scrollHeight);
            scrolled = true;
        }
    }
    setInterval(function(){
        load();
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

This way, load will be called every second, but since scrolled is in the outer scope, it will be the same variable for each call.

Comment: The problem now is that the php file loads after the scroll stript. I changed it to

               
      var scrolled = 1;
        function load(){
            $('#screen').load('includes/update.php');
            if(scrolled < 50){
                $("#screen").scrollTop($("#screen")[0].scrollHeight);
                scrolled++;
            }

And then it works. Have an idea for a better way?